# Unable to start second thread group if the first thread group is in infinite loop in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 Thread groups . The first thread group has an POST call to get an access token which expires every 5minutes , so I added a flow control Action to generate token every 2 minutes and pass it to a GET call in second Thread Group. But the problem is if I set the loop to infinite for the first thread group, the second one never gets invoked. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Praneeth, could you please post a screenshot of your test plan for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **untick** "Run Thread Groups consecutively" box in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

[image]

Alternatively you can move the logic to get/refresh the token to the "main" Thread Group and use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) to run this request once per 2 minutes